# Sort inside cond and if mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to sort my aggregation only if a condition is met.

This is what I have so far:

```
                    {
                        $cond: {
                           if: { $gte: [sort, "like"] },
                           then: { $divide: { $sort : { total_likes : -1 } } },
                           else: { $divide: '' }
                         }
                    }
```

`sort` is a variable that comes from a query parameter.

I want to sort by total_likes, only if `sort` is "likes". If it's not, I want to leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @schoenbl, if you want to match some condition in mongo aggregation, you should use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation. It will send the documents which fulfill the given condition.

> if: { $gte: [sort, "like"] }

In MongoDB, you are not allowed to compare string using "gte" operator. For string comparison in MongoDB, you get two operators:

1. for case sensitive [$cmp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/).
2. for case insensitive [$strcasecmp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strcasecmp/).

> then: { $divide: { $sort : { total_likes : -1 } } },

Next, you were using divide operator don't know what is your need but syntax is improper,
refer [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/), for better knowledge.

Also, you are doing sorting in $cond, which means you want to sort each element, and that is not possible because you can't sort without having a comparison as you are inside $cond operator and it is performing manipulation on a single document.

Now, according to your need, I have prepared the next stages which will give sorted document which contains "sort" equals to "like".

```
{$match:{"sort":"like"}},{$sort:{"total_likes":-1}}
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d50569fbe39828b4a22fba2"), "name" : "kyle", "sort" : "like", "total_likes" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5056a6be39828b4a22fba3"), "name" : "jack", "sort" : "like", "total_likes" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5056abbe39828b4a22fba4"), "name" : "john", "sort" : "like", "total_likes" : 1 }
```

Comment: That’s not what I’m trying to do. I only want to sort by like total when a query parameter exists. For example, sort can say “like” or it can say “date”. I only want to perform this action if the sort variable equals “like”, like an if statement in js. $gte should also be $eq, and it shouldn’t be in brackets.

Comment: @schoenbl could please elaborate your requirement, and where you want to use MongoDB query?